# TIdyverse mutate using value from column to reference another column value in perhaps a different row

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I have created a tibble thus:

```
library(tidyverse) 
set.seed(68) 
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
b <- runif(5) 
c <- c(1, 3, 3, 3, 1)
tib <- tibble(a, b, c)
```

which produces this

```
tib
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 0.924     1
2     2 0.661     3
3     3 0.402     3
4     4 0.637     3
5     5 0.353     1
```

I would like to add another column, d, which is the value of b according to the a value given in column c. The resulting data frame should look thus:

```
      a     b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 0.924     1 0.924
2     2 0.661     3 0.402
3     3 0.402     3 0.402
4     4 0.637     3 0.402
5     5 0.353     1 0.924
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: In `base R` you should use `tib$d <- tib$b[tib$c]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `c` to index the desired row of `b`:

```
tib %>% mutate(d = b[c])
```

> ```
>       a     b     c     d
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1 0.924     1 0.924
> 2     2 0.661     3 0.402
> 3     3 0.402     3 0.402
> 4     4 0.637     3 0.402
> 5     5 0.353     1 0.924
> ```